# What do the qualities applied to monsters mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the special abilities the unique/champion monsters can have?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66116/what-are-the-special-abilities-the-unique-champion-monsters-can-have)

I fought a gold colored zombie dubbed 'Nightmarish' in its qualities bar.

What does Nightmarish mean? What other qualities excist and what do they mean?

Comment: Def a dupe. I will vote to delete when the minimum time is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is abilities the monsters can have, the harder the difficulty the more it can have and some are only available on harder difficulties. A list can be found [here](http://www.diablowiki.net/Boss_modifier#Boss_Modifiers).

> **Nightmarish** is a boss modifier in Diablo III. This is another utility modifier that allows the boss to cast the Witch Doctor's
>   Horrify spell, which sends the player running around in random
>   directions for a short duration under the fear effect. While, like the
>   fast modifier, it isn't very dangerous on its own, it has the
>   potential to scale in effectiveness with other boss mods such as
>   molten.

[source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Nightmarish)