# Monster Affix List

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the special abilities the unique/champion monsters can have?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66116/what-are-the-special-abilities-the-unique-champion-monsters-can-have)

I often see other players complaining about the types of monsters they run into, like Mortar Arcane Wallers.  Now, I'm only halfway through Act 2 currently, so I am not sure what two of those affixes do.

Is there a list of affixes available to monsters, and their associated effects?