# What does the monster suffix "Chains" do?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the special abilities the unique/champion monsters can have?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66116/what-are-the-special-abilities-the-unique-champion-monsters-can-have)

There are sometimes champions which are bound together by chains:

[image: Also, screw these monsters]

In my particular example, their description read: "Vampiric Fire Chains". I have, however, also come across other types of Chains as well.

What does the effect do?

Answer (score 1):

stolen from Rachel at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67630/16350

> Fire Chains - Champion backs are attached by a fire chain. The Hero suffers damage if he touches or even gets near one of the fire links

[Rachel's original source](http://www.diablowiki.com/Rare_Monsters)

Comment: The effect of that list must be incomplete, though. I've seen enemies with other types of chains as well.

Comment: That makes sense, a lot of the lists and wikis I've been seeing are still reflecting pre-launch info from the Beta or publicity events. Everyone is still playing their hearts out, no time to go digging through raws, and Blizzard's site is super soft on useful information.

Comment: @heishe You might be thinking of Health Link monsters, which appear to have red-lines between them when you damage them. Invulnerable minions might have white chains too, although I can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

They cause damage to you, *a lot* of damage in some cases. I also have the impression that the mobs try to move in a way which puts the chains on top of the player.

The effect is "Fire chains", "Vamipric" is a second, separate effect.