# How can I know an enemy's level and damage to player?

Tags: diablo-iii

Sometimes, I see a whirling laser or some enemies chained together by some orange chain: those things kill a lot.

I don't know how much damage they cause, and I don't know what kind of move they pull out against me, but others seem to know that. How do I know? I've turned on every display in the options menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The affixes you're talking about are **Fire Chain** and **Arcane enchanted**. There's no way to tell the exact monster-level, but these two affixes only spawn in Nightmare and later difficulties (see [this question for more information about the affixes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66116/what-are-the-special-abilities-the-unique-champion-monsters-can-have)).

Generally you want to stay out of the arcane "laser-beams" (and yes, they deal a lot of damage), which shouldn't be that hard, unless you're jailed or frozen. You can also break the fire-chains by luring a monster away from the others.

Comment: how much damage they cost?

Answer (score 0):

Fire Chain. Just look below the name of the monsters at the top of the screen, in the middle.

Comment: and what's the monster level?