# Diablo 3 Monster Curses

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the special abilities the unique/champion monsters can have?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66116/what-are-the-special-abilities-the-unique-champion-monsters-can-have)

I have a Wizard, Witch Doctor and Demon Hunter, all of which are very early in Act I. Sometimes a small skull appears above my character. At other times (only with Odeg the Keywarden in the Fields of Misery?) my character is trapped inside a red column for a few seconds, or moves very slowly while a misty smoke moves around my feet. Are these curses from a monster? I've searched for a list or details of these, but I have not been able to find anything.

Comment: How is what characters you have part of the information needed for us to answer the question?

Comment: In case the curses/effects the monsters exhibit are the same effects which a Barbarian or Monk have, in which case I would not have seen them myself. I guess the same would be true of effects which the characters I have played may only acquire later. I'm thinking of the Bone Spear (not a curse, I know) which Obsidian Knights in D2 use; Necromancers have the same skill.

Comment: @fbueckert I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. The link asks what all of the available monster affxes are. This question asks where these column and mist-like effects are coming from.

Comment: I also voted to mark it as a duplicate, but Domenik VanBuskirk may have a point.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk Those effects are the special abilities that are mentioned; seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: @fbueckert The way I see it, the asker of the question you linked to knows what affixes are and wants a list of them. This person most likely does not know of affixes and wonders why he is having these things happen to him. They are pretty closely related but not exactly the same.

Comment: As the asker of the question, I think I must agree with Domenik VanBuskirk's last comment.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are being feared or snared by a Rare or Champion class enemy.

You can read on [all the possible modifiers](http://www.diablowiki.net/Boss_Modifiers) that these Rare/Champion enemies can have.

In your case you may have been fighting an enemy with the [Jailer](http://www.diablowiki.net/Jailer), [Nightmarish](http://www.diablowiki.net/Nightmarish), or [Plagued](http://www.diablowiki.net/Plagued) modifiers.

Jailers would give you that red column around your character which will stop you from moving and attacking.

Nightmarish foes would make the skull appear above your character. When they 'fear' you, you lose control of your character and the skull appears signalling that you have been feared.

Plagued enemies *seem* to be closest to the 'mist' you describe so this may or not be it. The plague from these enemies is green and very noticeable. You should be able to tell if this is what you are talking about or not when this happens again.

Comment: Could the misty smoke be the web spit from a [spider](http://www.diablowiki.net/Spider)?