# Frozen, Immobilized, anything else that stops you from moving?

Tags: diablo-iii

What all status affects in Diablo 3 can cause you immobility, and not being able to move?

Do these certain status affects have any defense? Is there any item, or gear, or skill that can prevent you from ever getting immobilized (like frozen).

Comment: There are some skills you can use to break free from these. Demon hunter's Vault can break from snares at the least (not sure about frozen), and the Monk's Serenity(?) with the CC-blocking rune. Never tried this but the Wizard's teleport may also work same as DH's Vault.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the special abilities the unique/champion monsters can have?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66116/what-are-the-special-abilities-the-unique-champion-monsters-can-have)

Comment: I didn't ask "What special abilities do monsters have" I asked about protection against certain status ailments and immobility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**These are all of the immobilization effects:**

- Jailer
- Frozen
- Stun
- Nightmarish (doesn't technically immobilize, but takes away control for a moment)

[Ice Climbers make you immune to all immobilization effects](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ice-climbers) (correct me if I'm wrong), the only other thing I know that helps with it is to stack "Reduces the duration of control impairing effects by x%" stat.

**Skills that break CC (Crowd control effects):**

**Barbarian**

- Wrath of Berserker (breaks all CC and grants immunity for the duration)
- Leap (can be used while jailed, does not break CC, if timed correctly can avoid CC)
- Furious Charge (can be used while jailed, does not break CC)

**Crusader**

- Law of Justice [Bravery rune] (Breaks all CC when activated and grants immunity for duration)
- Iron Skin (Breaks CC and grants immunity for the duration)
- Akarat's Champion (Breaks CC and grants immunity for the duration)
- Steed Charge (doesn't break CC, but grants immunity for the duration)
- Falling Sword (doesn't break CC, if timed correctly can avoid CC)

**Demon Hunter**

- Smoke Screen (breaks all CC)
- Vault (breaks snare and jailer)

**Monk**

- Epiphany (breaks all CC and grants immunity for the duration)
- Serenity (breaks all CC and grants immunity for the duration)
- Dashing Strike (doesn't break CC, can be used while jailed)
- Seven-sided Strike (doesn't break CC, if timed correctly can avoid CC)

**Witch Doctor**

- Spirit Walk (breaks all CC and grants immunity for the duration)

**Wizard**

- Teleport (can be used while jailed, does not break CC)

[Source for skills](http://www.diablowiki.net/Escape_Skills)

P.S Feel free to correct me if anything is wrong, I haven't tested some of the skills myself and I usually only pay attention if a skill breaks freeze.

Comment: barb leap lets you move while jailed fyi

Comment: it lets you move, but afaik it does not actually break jail. I guess I can add it to the answer...

Comment: Yes, Leap and Teleport do not *break* jail, but allow you to carry your cell with you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on Teleport. I originally didn't intend to add skills that didn't break CC, but I guess I may as well... :)

Comment: Does Steed Charge allow running through walls? I've not managed to in my experience of trying it out in place of Falling Sword. I guess Waller doesn't count for CC?

Comment: @DavidYell waller indeed does not count for CC as it doesn't directly affect your character.

Comment: It sure feels like it when you get pinned in with 3 walls in a triangle right on top of your character! As much as I like Steed Charge, I might have to stick with Falling Sword for this reason.